# Чтение файлов в цикле через popen

Tags: c++

Через `popen` вызовом системной команды получаем список файлов, далее заносим их в массив.

```
FILE                 *fresponse;
char                 buff[512];
const char           * fname;
int   flistArrSize         = 0;
static const char *flist[] = {0};

fresponse = popen( "find /tmp -name php* | grep -v [.] | grep  php*", "r");

while( fgets( buff, sizeof(buff), fresponse)!=NULL){
       flistArrSize++;
       fname = buff;
       flist[flistArrSize] = fname;
}
```

Как правильно сделать, чтобы соответствующие пути заполнили элементы массива?

В данном коде в результате все элементы массива имеют одинаковое значение.

К примеру, файлы:

```
phpSdFefrS
phpVdFefrF
```

Но в результат выполнения программы все элементы массива заполняются значением `phpVdFefrF`.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: отметьте правильный ответ

Comment: если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Причина в том, что строки не присваивают через `=`, есть функция `strcpy`. При присваивание строк, вы по сути присваиваете указатель, значение под которым будет изменено на следующей итерации цикла. Да и `const char *flist[] = {0};` эквивалентно `const char *flist[1] = {0};` и создаст массив с 1 ячейкой.

Замените на `char flist[MaxFile][MaxLen];`. `MaxLen` можете взять *256*, к примеру.

И пишите `strcpy(flist[flistArrSize],fname);`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Ты сохраняешь не сами строки, а адрес буффера. А буффер один. Тебе нужно дуплицировать строки:

```
flist[flistArrSize] = strdup(buff);
```

Естественно, потом элементы этого списка нужно очистить при помощи free(), когда станут не нужны.

UPD: а это вообще не нужно:

```
fname = buff
```

этим ты просто присваиваешь адрес указателя, но не копируешь строку.

UPD2: а ты память где-то выделяешь под это:

```
static const char *flist[] = {0};
```

? Или хочется динамики? Тогда нужно что-то вроде:

```
static const char **flist = NULL;
// ...
while( fgets( buff, sizeof(buff), fresponse)!=NULL){
       flistArrSize++;
       const char **tmp = (const char**)realloc(flist, flistArrSize * sizeof(const char*));
       if (!tmp) {
           // память кончилась, что-то сделать нужно
       }
       flist = tmp;
       flist[flistArrSize - 1] = strdup(buff);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ

Comment: Рано, у тебя там других проблем есть много. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Укажите, пожалуйста на ошибки. Код в принципе выполняет поставленную задачу.

```
    FILE  *fresponse;
char   buff[512];
char  *fname;
int    flistArrSize  = 0;
int    maxPSocket    = 300;
static char *flist[] = {0};


fresponse = popen( "find /tmp -name php* | grep -v [.] | grep  php*", "r");



while( fgets( buff, sizeof(buff), fresponse)!=NULL){

       flistArrSize++;
       flist[flistArrSize] = strdup(buff);
 } 



if( flistArrSize>maxPSocket-1 || flistArrSize==0){
    return false;
}



for( int i=1; i<=flistArrSize; i++){
     printf( "%s",flist[i]);   
}


pclose( fresponse);
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: flist[flistArrSize] = strdup(buff); - вы из зенитного пулемёта стреляете себе по ногам.